# Sum of multiple array elements and put this sum in table by index (x,y)

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, sum, tabular

I have the following data (loaded by ajax):

```
[
  {
    "x":     [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5],
    "y":     [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5],
    "Value": [18, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4],
  },
  {
    "x":     [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5],
    "y":     [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5],
    "Value": [16, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4],
  },
  {
    "x":     [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5],
    "y":     [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5],
    "Value": [14, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4],
  }
]
```

And I have [a 5x5 table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4aaI.png).

How can I calculate sum of each multiple element of "value" and put it in the table of right index?

My js code for now:

```
function risk(data) {
    let sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let b = data[i].Value;
      console.log(b); // (10) [18, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4]
                      // (10) [16, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4]
                      // (10) [14, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4]
    }
}
```

The end result must be like this:

[image]

Comment: please add the wanted data structure for the result as well.

Comment: @ninaScholz Do you mean the table in html?

Comment: So what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an object for collecting the values. For getting the result in back into the table, you could iterate the coordinates and get a value.

```js
var data = [{ x: [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5], y: [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5], Value: [18, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4] }, { x: [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5], y: [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5], Value: [16, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4] }, { x: [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5], y: [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5], Value: [14, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4] }],
    sum = data.reduce((r, {x, y, Value}) => 
        (x.forEach((x, i) => {
        r[x] = r[x] || {};
        r[x][y[i]] = (r[x][y[i]] || 0) + Value[i];
    }), r), {});
    
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Oh, it seems like result i was looking for.. Now need to find out how to put the axact data i need in the right table row and column..Thank you!!!!

Comment: do you know how to make calulate "zero" value in new Object?

Comment: you could iterate `x` and `y` and access the value with a default value, like `(sum[x] || {})[y] || 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to build your "result" matrix, adding "Value" to its appropriate `x` and `y` coordinate in the matrix as you iterate through all the elements in your original data.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "x":     [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5],
    "y":     [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5],
    "Value": [18, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4],
  },
  {
    "x":     [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5],
    "y":     [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5],
    "Value": [16, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4],
  },
  {
    "x":     [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5],
    "y":     [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5],
    "Value": [14, 15, 11, 12, 9, 2, 33, 12, 2, 4],
  }
];

const res = new Array(5).fill(0).map(n => new Array(5).fill(0));
data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr.Value.forEach((v, i) => acc[curr.x[i] - 1][curr.y[i] - 1] += v);
  return res;
}, res);

console.log(res);
```